# Need to dynamically calculate refresh interval depending on time format passed in as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a react component that accepts an array of 2 moment.js time formats  that will be used as props in the component to then render the time in a small clock widget in the format passed in. I need to dynamically calculate the refresh interval depending on time format passed in and being utilized. So if only needing seconds due to time format passed in being a second counter, interval refreshes every second, if only needing minutes, refresh rate will be around every minute. Couldn't find anything that has helped yet so asking for some advice. Thanks in advance. Here is my code, sorry it looks so rough right now.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

// Styles
import Style from 'Components/Header/Header.module.css';

class ClockWidget extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = { 
            time: moment().format('hh:mm a'),
            toggle: true,
            timerID: null
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }


    setTime() {

        this.timerID = setInterval(() => {

            if (this.state.toggle == true) {

                this.setState({
                    time: moment().format(this.props.timeFormat[0])
                })

            } else if (this.state.toggle == false) {

                this.setState({

                    time: moment().format(this.props.timeFormat[1])
                })
            }
            console.log("State: ", this.state);
        }, this.state.toggle ? 1000 : 60000);
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        this.setTime();
    }

    handleClick() {

        if (this.state.toggle) {
            this.setState({ toggle: false })
        } else {
            this.setState({ toggle: true })
        }
    }

    render() {  

        return ( 
            <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                <p className={Style.action}> {this.state.time} </p>            
            </div>
        )}
    }
    ClockWidget.defaultProps = {
        timeFormat: ['hh:mm a', 'HH:mm']
    }

export default ClockWidget;
```

Comment: just use this prop while calling `setTime` ?

Comment: You seem to have only 2 formats and you set the one to be used base on the value of `this.state.toggle`. Can't you simply do something like this: `setInterval(...., this.state.toggle ? 1000 : 60000)` ?

Comment: Also, you'll need to keep a reference to the interval's ID so you can cancel it and create another one when the format is changed.

Comment: @ Titus Keep a reference how?

Answer (score 0):

do some changes...

```
in your state {
    this.timerId = null
}

.
.
.
.

setTime(time = null, toggle = null) {

    this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.state.toggle) {
            this.setState({
                time: moment().format(this.props.timeFormat[0]),
            })
        } else if (!this.state.toggle) {
            this.setState({
                time: moment().format(this.props.timeFormat[1]),
            })
        }
    }, 1000)
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setTime();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerId)
}
```

and if you are gonna update then use update lifecycle methods togather with mount lifecycle methods

Comment: I have <ClockWidget /> being rendered on top of another component so the unmount won't work there I think?

Comment: no for that component it will get called before it's parent component gets unmount

Comment: updated code. Still having issue getting it to work. Upon click it's still updating every second.

Comment: after clockwidget gets unmount timer is gonna get cleared for sure... only after it gets unmount